# How to compile gcc with static library?

Tags: c, linux, static-libraries

I have static library `lib.a` and in all tutorials using:

```
gcc -o main main.o -L. -lib
```

But I cant, I have errors:

```
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lib
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I need to use:

```
gcc -o main main.o -L. -lib.a
```

Why? What should I do to repair it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of `gcc -l`:

> -l*library*:
>
> The linker searches a standard list of directories for the library, which is actually a **file named liblibrary.a**. The linker then uses this file as if it had been specified precisely by name.
>
> ...
>
> The only difference between using an -l option and specifying a file name is that -l surrounds library with ‘lib’ and ‘.a’ and searches several directories.

So you cannot use `-l` with a library named 'lib.a'. Use 'lib.a' without the `-l` to include it. Of course, you cannot use `-L` then to set the directories to be searched for this particular library.

Comment: But i am using  -L no -l

Comment: You are using both: `-L` with '.' and `-l` with 'ib', which makes `-L. -lib`.

Comment: Don't use `-l`! Use `gcc -o main main.o lib.a`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the error with this line ?

```
gcc -o main main.o -L. -llib
```

As MicroVirus found in the documentation, you will have to rename your library in liblib.a to use my previous line or just pass your library to gcc like a simple file.

Comment: If your library is called llib.a, yes.

Comment: No, the library is supposed to be named lib.a as in your example. The -l parameter with your library name after, indicates to gcc, what is the name of your library.

Comment: Then, maybe it's your operating system or your gcc version. Can you tell us what are they ?